# how do you disconnect ssh in emacs shell mode

Tags: ssh

In a regular terminal, I do

~ enter d

to disconnect from a ssh session.

sometimes I do ~ enter Ctl-z

to minimize/bg the ssh process

Is this possible while inside a `M-x shell` buffer in emacs.

(I use -nw terminal mode)

Comment: SSH session starts a shell on remote end to communicate with it.  If you terminate that shell, the SSH session will also terminate.  So, for example, if remote shell is anything compatible with `sh`, then typing `exit` will terminate the session.

Comment: sometimes I do ~ enter Ctl-z to minimize/bg the ssh process. So yeah I need a solution that's more general purpose

Comment: From https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html: `Eshell has no job control, so you can not suspend or background the current process, or bring a background process into the foreground. `

Comment: I am not referring to eshell, nor ansi-term. I am using M-x shell

Answer (score 1):

> In a regular terminal, I do
>
> ~ enter d
>
> to disconnect from a ssh session.

It would be <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> for me, and that also works fine if I'd run `ssh` from a `M-x shell` buffer, with the exception that comint doesn't send the input to the process at all until <kbd>RET</kbd> is typed, so it needs to be:

<kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

> sometimes I do ~ enter Ctl-z
>
> to minimize/bg the ssh process

<kbd>~</kbd><kbd>C-z</kbd> here and this just needs a bit of `quoted-insert` to prevent Emacs from capturing the `C-z`, so the following works for me if I'd run `ssh` from a `M-x shell` buffer:

<kbd>~</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-z</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>